# Can't use facebook app with own account

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Hi I have problem with a facebook app I created.
I am using this app to make it possible to login with facebook on one of my websites.
The problem is that if I login with my account the website only has standard permissions but if someone else logs in with his account he has all the permissions the webpage is asking for.
I also tried deleting the app and logging in another time again but this also didn't work. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?
The extended permissions I am asking for are: email and publish_actions
I also added them in the app settings on developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Prior to installing an app, the app install screen will allow you to view or control who sees the activity the app posts to Facebook on your behalf.
>
> After you install an app, you can view and manage its settings in your App Settings.
>
> To get to your App Settings:
>   Open the account dropdown menu  at the top right corner of Facebook and click Account Settings.
>   From the menu in the left column, select Apps. From here, you can manage settings for each individual app you've added.
>   To change who can see your app activities from App Settings:
>   Click Edit next to the app whose settings you’d like to change.
>   Next to Posts on your behalf, modify who sees posts the app makes on your behalf using the in-line audience selector.
>   Note: Selecting a different audience for your app activity will only change who can see new stories the app posts for you on your timeline. The audience for previously shared stories will stay the same. This setting only controls the audience of posts on Facebook, not posts within the app itself.
>
> You can also manage your app settings and privacy in the App Center via the My Apps page
>
> http://www.facebook.com/help/262314300536014/

You can enable permissions after the app is installed like above. You may be missing certain permissions depending on your own privacy settings

Comment: sadly you only can delete permissions there... :( I think the problem is the access token is there any way of renewing the access token?

Comment: It's easier to invalidate a user token, you just use the me/permissions (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/permissions) connection with a DELETE request.

That will remove the app for the logged in user.
You can try that from the explorer tool, just select DELETE on the select box left to the path field.